# Rolling Sum - Year by Year/Month By Month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to group several accounts together while keep a rolling / renewing balance. The query using one account:

```
SELECT FiscalPeriod, BalanceAmt,
       SUM(balanceamt) OVER(ORDER BY fiscalperiod) as BalanceAmt
FROM EpicorLive10.Erp.GLPeriodBal
WHERE FiscalYear = '2018'
AND BalanceAcct IN ('01260|0000|000')
GROUP BY fiscalperiod,BalanceAmt
ORDER BY FiscalPeriod
```

OUTPUT

[image: Output1]

With two accounts output:

[image: Output2]

As you can see, it doesn't group both account together..

What I want to happen is to add several accounts, sum everything / group everything within the 12 rows of fiscal period / year.

Ultimately, I'd need:
[All accounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35Fgm.jpg)

Any advice is appreciated.

```
--UPDATE** Current Query**  
select Datex, balanceamt into #temp 
FROM EpicorLive10.Erp.GLPeriodBal as A  
JOIN EpicorLive10.dbo.Date_Fiscal as B  
ON a.FiscalPeriod = b.Fiscal_Period and a.FiscalYear = b.Fiscal_Year   
WHERE FiscalYear = '2018'  
AND BalanceAcct IN (   
'01260|0000|000',  
'01261|0000|000',  
'01262|0000|000',  
'01263|0000|000',  
'01264|0000|000',  
'01555|0000|000',  
'01560|0000|000',  
'01245|0000|000',  
'01250|0000|000')  
GROUP BY Datex,BalanceAmt  


declare @rollup table (rollupid int identity, fiscalperiod int,     balanceamt float)  
insert @rollup  
select Datex, sum(balanceamt) from #temp  
group by Datex  
order by Datex  


declare @holding table (fiscalperiod int, balanceamt float, runningbal     float)  
declare @iterator int=0  
declare @currentbal float =0  
while @iterator<=(select max(rollupid) from @rollup) begin  
select @currentbal=@currentbal+balanceamt from @rollup where       fiscalperiod=@iterator  
insert @holding  
select fiscalperiod, balanceamt, @currentbal from  
@rollup where  
fiscalperiod=@iterator  
 set @iterator=@iterator+1  
 end  

select * from @holding  

drop table #temp
```

Account Table: [Account Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gg8FP.jpg)
Date_Fiscal Table: [Date_Fiscal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2WQM.jpg)

Comment: what exactly is the output you are looking for?

Comment: Basically - I want the accounts to be combined.

Comment: Did Gordon's answer work for you?

Comment: In the 2nd output with 2 accounts, is separates the two accounts; two "Fiscal_Periods". I'm looking to sum each account by fiscal period. The 3 column shows the opening balance minus the 2nd column balance amount.

Comment: OK see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select Datex, balanceamt into #temp 
FROM EpicorLive10.Erp.GLPeriodBal  A  
JOIN EpicorLive10.dbo.Date_Fiscal  B  
ON a.FiscalPeriod = b.Fiscal_Period and a.FiscalYear = b.Fiscal_Year   
WHERE FiscalYear = '2018'  
AND BalanceAcct IN (   
'01260|0000|000',  
'01261|0000|000',  
'01262|0000|000',  
'01263|0000|000',  
'01264|0000|000',  
'01555|0000|000',  
'01560|0000|000',  
'01245|0000|000',  
'01250|0000|000')  
GROUP BY Datex, BalanceAmt  


declare @rollup table (rollupid int identity, Datex datetime, balanceamt float)  
insert @rollup  
select Datex, sum(balanceamt) from #temp  
group by Datex  
order by Datex  


declare @holding table (Datex datetime, balanceamt float, runningbal float)  
declare @iterator int=1  
declare @currentbal float =0  
while @iterator<=(select max(rollupid) from @rollup) begin  
select @currentbal=@currentbal+balanceamt from @rollup where @iterator=rollupid   
insert @holding  
select Datex, balanceamt, @currentbal from  
@rollup where @iterator=rollupid     
 set @iterator=@iterator+1  
 end  

select * from @holding  

drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you use window functions with aggregation:

```
SELECT FiscalPeriod, BalanceAmt,
       SUM(SUM(balanceamt)) OVER (ORDER BY fiscalperiod) as BalanceAmt
FROM EpicorLive10.Erp.GLPeriodBal
WHERE FiscalYear = '2018' AND BalanceAcct IN ('01260|0000|000')
GROUP BY fiscalperiod
ORDER BY FiscalPeriod;
```

Note that your `IN` looks strange.  It looks more like regular expression, which SQL Server does not support.

The `SUM(SUM())` looks strange at first, but you'll get used to it quickly enough.  The inner `SUM()` is from the aggregation.  The outer `SUM()` is for the window function.

Comment: SUM(SUM()) ... With my lizard brain, I've always used sub-queries or CTEs for this.

Comment: @CGiles . . . You are the OP and can choose any answer you like.  But why you would choose a longer, more complicated, and less performant solution is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FiscalPeriod, Sum(BalanceAmt),
       SUM(balanceamt) OVER(ORDER BY fiscalperiod  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as BalanceAmt
FROM EpicorLive10.Erp.GLPeriodBal
WHERE FiscalYear = '2018'
AND BalanceAcct IN ('01260|0000|000')
GROUP BY fiscalperiod,BalanceAmt
ORDER BY FiscalPeriod
```

What are the accounts? Are thet 01260, 0000 & 000?
If yes your IN would be ('01260', '0000', '000')
This is untested but I took it from a similar one I have.

Hope it helps

Comment: Nope, the accounts are actually the first set of numbers. Daniel's answer was the solution though. Thanks!